# Is inline summation index has different functionality, such as $\sum_{x,y} f(X,Y)$?

Tags: calculus, probability, summation, notation

I find different papers use summation with a different style than other summation in the same paper. This thing repeats in more than one paper. Therefore I believe this is summation do different work than normal one.

[image] <- from the paper 1

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lhma.png)<-from the paper 2

What does this summation call?

What does it do?

Paper use this kind of summation:

1. Jeffrey–divergence eq, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3703241_Non-parametric_similarity_measures_for_unsupervised_texturesegmentation_and_image_retrieval
2. 9+ 10 eq, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271616304324

Comment: I still looking for answers

Answer (score 0):

Those ambiguous context dependent expressions could be open to different interpretation.

$\sum_k$: This is just a summarized standard sum of some index $k$ over some discrete domain $K$. One has to derive from the context which is that domain (perhaps the histogram samples in this case?)

$\sum_{ij}c_{ij}$: This is the same case, but the sum is double. Again this is context dependent. One could think on independent domains for $i$ and $j$, or even coupled $i,j$ pairs to be included on the sum. I was unable to check this second paper.

$\sum_XP_{XY}$: In this case, the context reads for a marginal discrete distribution. Again, omiting the domain of the random variable $X$ creates an ambiguity. Which in this case is increased by the ambiguity of making no difference between the random variable name $X$, the values it can take, and the values considered for the sum. Sometimes, we can assume too much.

Edit:

From the context, the expressions:
$$
P_{XY}=\frac1{\sum_{ij}c_{ij}}JH\\
P_{X}=\sum_{Y}P_{XY}\\
P_{Y}=\sum_{X}P_{XY}
$$

are equivalent to:
$$
P_{XY}(ij)=\frac1{\sum_{i'=1}^m\sum_{j'=1}^nc_{i'j'}}c_{ij}\\
P_{X}(i)=\sum_{j=1}^nP_{XY}(ij)\\
P_{Y}(j)=\sum_{i=1}^nP_{XY}(ij)
$$

From the paper $c_{ij}$ are the elements of the matrix $JH$, hence $P_{XY}$ is just normalizing the histogram matrix $JH$ in order to be interpreted as a joint distribution.

And from here, $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are vectors, obtaining by summing one of the indexes of the previously obtained matrix, which can be interpreted as the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I think you did not get my question. My question is the inline summation of these papers just like normal summation or not?  if same.. why the authors use inline style while using normal with other summation in the same paper.

Comment: the 2nd paper http://www.geosimulation.cn/Papers/isprs_image_registration.pdf

Comment: I can understand from your ans there is no difference between write index under sigma or inline text. thanks for your update

Comment: Check the edit. These are the proper replacement for the overloaded notation. I hope this is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example seems to be the one that’s worrying you. The “$ij$” is written to the lower right of the $\sum$ symbol. I think this is what you mean by “in-line” positioning.

The positioning of the $ij$ doesn’t mean anything. It doesn’t matter whether the $ij$ is to the right of the $\sum$ symbol or below it. The meaning of the summation is the same in both cases.